# Processing: Turning a string of random words into a single sentence

Tags: string, processing

I am trying to generate pseudorandom formattable sentences in Processing.

I found many example sketches that separate a sentence into a list of words, but none that merge separated words into one sentence.

For example, is there a way for me to convert the string words[n] into a single sentence?

```
String[] Space = {
" " };
String[] Verbs = { 
"like", "kill", "taste", "save" };
String[] PossessiveAdjectives = { 
"your", "her", "his", "my" };
String[] Nouns = { 
"apple", "bank", "cat", "dog" };

void setup(){
size(800,400);
background(0);
textAlign(CENTER);
textSize(100);
new_sentence();
}
void draw(){
}
void write_word(String[] words){
int n = int(random(words.length));
print(words[n]);
text(words[n], 0.5*width ,0.5*height+25);
}

void new_sentence(){
write_word(Verbs);
write_word(Space);
write_word(PossessiveAdjectives);
write_word(Space);
write_word(Nouns); 
}

void mousePressed(){
setup(); 
}
```

Comment: Sure. How do you define a sentence? NOUN+VERB is an example. You'd select 1 word from the nouns array, and 1 word from the verbs array. What about that is giving you trouble?

Comment: That part is already figured out. 
This code prints sentences in the form of "verb+possessive adjective+noun"; however, when I attempt to put them into the text() function, each word simultaneously draws in the same location.

Comment: Well, the program is displaying the words at the same location because that's exactly what you're telling the program to do. Instead, you need to build a String out of all of the words you chose, then display that.

Comment: I feel extremely stupid. I tried that earlier using this:

`String Sentence = Verbs[verb] PossessiveAdjectives[adjective] Nouns[noun];`

But processing kept giving me an error.

Luckily I just discovered that "+" is not only used for numbers.

`String Sentence = Verbs[verb]+" "+PossessiveAdjectives[adjective]+" "+Nouns[noun];`

Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction!

Comment: please don't edit your post to add all the "solved" parts, just wait 2 days, answer your own question the proper way, and then accept that answer. It'd be useful to do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

It now contains the randomly selected words in String Sentence and combines them with +" "+

```
int screenWidth = 800;
int screenHeight = 400;

void setup() {
  size(screenWidth, screenHeight);
  sentence();
}

void sentence() {
  String[] Verbs = { 
    "like", "kill", "taste", "save"
  };
  String[] PossessiveAdjectives = { 
    "your", "her", "his", "my"
  };
  String[] Nouns = { 
    "apple", "bank", "cat", "dog"
  };

  int verb = int(random(Verbs.length));
  int possessiveAdjective = int(random(PossessiveAdjectives.length));
  int noun = int(random(Nouns.length));

  String Sentence = Verbs[verb]+" "+PossessiveAdjectives[possessiveAdjective]+" "+Nouns[noun];
  println(Sentence);

  background(0);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(100);
  text(Sentence, 0.5*screenWidth, 0.5*screenHeight+25);
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
  sentence();
}
```

---